# math plus operator in query. summing up .select specified count variables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I been trying to add another joins table like shown in rails guide(e.g. publication_comments). Then I call select on specified columns to count, probably so far it's working.

Idea of this is to plus reviews_count and pub_count = SUM. however I faced a problem how to plus in query reviews_count and pub_count and order: "SUM DESC".

Is it possible to make like I think? and how?

So far I have this code:

```
 @publication = Publication.joins(:reviews, :publication_comments)
                                  .select('"publications".*, count("reviews".id) as reviews_count, count("publication_comments".id) as pub_count')
                                  .group('"publications".id')
                                  .order("reviews_count DESC")
```

Comment: What db do you use? This will be dependent on sql command.

Comment: I use SQLite3. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: And you will use sqlite in production? You understand that the sql functions might be different between SQLite and for example Postgres?

Comment: Yes, planning to use sqlite in production.

Comment: If I try `SELECT col1 + col2 FROM "some_table";` in postgres it works well, so I guess it would be possible in sqlite as well. Question is if you can put it in order clause. If not you may always order by `reviews_count, pub_count` as this should be effectively the same as ordering by sum.

Comment: And concerning sqlite in production either you really know what you're doing or you should reconsider your db choice.

Comment: Building on what @MichaelSzyndel says, try replacing `count("reviews".id) as reviews_count, count("publication_comments".id) as pub_count` with `count("reviews".id) + count("publication_comments".id) as my_count` and do `.order("my_count DESC")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@publication = Publication.joins(:reviews, :publication_comments)
    .select('"publications".*, count("reviews".id) + count("publication_comments".id) as my_count')
    .group('"publications".id')
    .order("my_count DESC")
```